# Best architecture for new web site calling existing services (ASP.NET Web API with authentication and authorisation)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, oauth, asp.net-identity

**What I am trying to achieve:**

I currently have mobile apps on top of services and would like to add a web site on top of the same services.

**Services details:**

ASP.NET Web API project using OAuth (bearer token) and Identity for authentication and authorisation.

- Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi 5.2.3
- Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth 3.0.1
- Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core 2.2.1

**Mobile details:**

Xamarin projects.

- Xamarin.Forms 2.3.3.193

**What architecture should I use for the web site?**

- Create a new ASP.NET MVC project and call my current services from the MVC controllers?  This seems bad because:

  - I would have 2 layers of controllers (web site MVC controllers calling services API controllers)
  - I would need to store bearer tokens in cookies
  - I would need to manage the tokens and cookies expirations
- Create a new ASP.NET MVC project and call current services database directly?  This seems bad because:

  - I would have to duplicate the models in the services project and in the web site project
- Create a new ASP.NET project and call my current services using ajax?  This seems bad because:

  - I would need to create my own register/login pages
  - I would need to store bearer tokens in cookies
  - I would need to manage the tokens and cookies expirations
  - I would need to say bye to future social authentication (OAUTH2) implementation because I wouldn’t be using OWIN

Thanks,

fcorbeil

Comment: If you already have the API a brand new MVC app shouldn't be such a bad choice. If you have your models stored in a different project just reference them to the MVC one. As for the services, them would work perfectly with the new application. This all can be achieved without changing almost nothing to the current implementation.

Comment: Hi Cristian, your absolutely right!  Sharing the models is just perfect, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already have the API a brand new MVC app shouldn't be such a bad choice. If you have your models stored in a different project just reference them to the MVC one. As for the services, them would work perfectly with the new application. This all can be achieved without changing almost nothing to the current implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I am working on a project and using a similar architecture.

I decided to create an Angular project for the website front end and all it does is talk to the Web API. Angular handles the JWT authentication really well. If you've never worked with Angular before, it is really nice to work with.

However, a vanilla ASP.NET MVC web app would work just as well.

It depends on how comfortable you are with Angular, or how  willing you are are to learning it! :)